# What's the best way to validate that a value is one of a set of possible values?

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, what is the idiomatic way to validate that a value is one of a set of possible values?

I initially did something like this:

```
(let [size :grande]
  (make-latte (condp = size
                :tall :tall
                :grande :grande)))
```

The above is useful because if no clause matches an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown.

But then I found this more comfortable to do:

```
(let [size :grande]
  (make-latte (or (some #{:tall :grande} [size])
                  (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "I don't know that size")))
```

This technique works well because it allows for more possible values, e.g.

```
(some #{:short :tall :grande :venti} [size])
```

What's the best way to do this? Am I right in thinking that `clojure.core` does not have a function that does this already?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`(some #{:short :tall :grande :venti} [size])`

is equivalent to

`(#{:short :tall :grande :venti} size)`

That's because sets are functions. For a generic collection you can use `contains?`.

Edit: as user1571406 notes below, be aware that `contains?` tests for keys, not values.

Comment: Although do note that `contains?` checks whether the value is a **key** in an associative collection. So `#{:venti :grande} contains? :venti` and `:grande` but `[:venti :grande]` will `contains?` *0 and 1*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pre-condition in the `make-latte` function itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8607359/609639